# implicit operator bool() is not responding to my call

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am testing a template:

```
template<typename Key>
struct _Tarray<Key, char>{

    map<const Key, string> data; 

    //stuff

    operator bool(){cout << " just testing"; return false;}    //trying to call this, but its not answering
};
```

So, I am driving it like this:

```
_Tarray<int, char> out;
  cout << out;
```

Here is my overloaded `operator<<`:

```
template<typename T, typename U>       
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const _Tarray<T, U>& var){

    //now i expect operator bool() to be called here

    if(var){os << " Yes !";}         //and bool is not being called. my compiler (g++) is angry
    else{cout << " No !";}

    return os;
}
```

Which gives me

```
./template.h: In instantiation of 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const _Tarray<T, U>&) [with T = int; U = char; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]':
./template.h:128:41:   required from 'void var_dump(const T&) [with T = _Tarray<int, char>]'
functions.cpp:12:21:   required from here
./template.h:122:5: error: passing 'const _Tarray<int, char>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     if(var){os << "heheheheh";}
     ^
./template.h:73:5: note:   in call to '_Tarray<Key, char>::operator bool() [with Key = int]'
```

Why is it giving me a compiler error and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: what does get called?

Comment: This question fails to meet the "complete" requirement for a [mcve]. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: nothing ! just a compiler error: check new edit above.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie Please stop using stack snippets for non HTML, CSS, JS code.  For normal code just use the code block button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` is a `const _Tarray<T, U>&`. The important information here is that it is `const`, which means, that **no function can be called from `var` if they modify the properties of `var`**.

The compiler doesn't *know* that your `operator bool` doesn't modify anything, so it fails. You have to explicitly state that your `operator bool` won't modify `_Tarray`, by specifying the function as `const`:

```
//Note the 'const', operator bool own't change anything, so the call from a const
//instance is legal
operator bool() const
{
    std::cout << "Just testing\n";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `operator<<` `var` is `const`.  Since it is `const` you can only call `const` qualified member functions.  Since your `operator bool` is not marked as `const` you cannot use it.  To fix it change `operator bool` to

```
operator bool() const {cout << " just testing"; return false;}
```